# If statement for ffdf object

Tags: r, if-statement, ff

I have an `ffdf` object `x` that holds a dataset with variables `y` and `z`. Due to millions of rows it needs to be stored as an `ffdf` object. My question is this:

I want to create a new variable within this object `q`, that is dependent on the value of `z`.

`z` takes three values: 1, 2, and 3, and when z=1 I would like `q=A`, when `z=2`, I would like `q=B` and when `z=3`, I would like `q=C`.

In reality z has about 30 levels, and I have tried the `ffifelse` statement which seems very inefficient. I have also tried the following:

`x$q[x$z==1] <- ff("A")`

but I then get the following error:

> Error: length(value) == n is not TRUE

I would appreciate any help on transforming and creating new variables within an `ffdf` object.

Comment: Please provide a small amount of your data. Also, try `x$q[x$z==1] <- ff("A")`?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be x$q[x$z==1] <- ff("A") I have modified the original post. Didn't work though.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538186/rffhow-to-add-a-new-column-which-depends-on-other-elements-in-the-same-row-in/29538691#29538691